# Applying prior weeks growth to future weeks

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use prior weeks growth to anticipate future results.

I want to take the past three weeks year over year growth by day, and apply it to the future weeks prior year's results to anticipiate my future results.

```
--Future Data in which the average growth needs to be applied

SELECT DOW, SiteNum, dtDate, Measure1, Measure2 from tData 
    WHERE dtDate > NOW();

--Obtains growth average, by DayOfWeek, by Site    
SELECT TY.DOW, TY.SiteNum, AVG(1 + ((TY.Measure1 - LY.Measure1) / LY.Measure1)) as Measure1_GrowthAvg, AVG(1 + ((TY.Measure2 - LY.Measure2) / LY.Measure2)) as Measure2_GrowthAvg
    FROM tData TY
      INNER JOIN tData LY
          ON TY.WeekNum = LY.WeekNum
              AND TY.DOW = LY.DOW
              AND TY.SiteNum = LY.SiteNum
              AND TY.YearNum = '2019'
              AND LY.YearNum = '2018'
    WHERE TY.dtDate between DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -21 DAY) AND NOW() 
    GROUP BY TY.DOW, TY.SiteNum
    ORDER BY TY.SITENUM, TY.DOW;
```

I need to apply the Measured1_GrowthAvg to the first query's Measure1, and MEasured2_GrowthAvg to Measure2.  If the Measured1_GrowthAvg is 1.5 for DOW 1,  and the future Measure1 for the same DOW is 1000, the projected result would be 1500.

I have sample data in a dbfiddle here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2YYhgN9aBUUFLK49g8uocX/5

The first query is jsut future data that needs the average growth applied, and the second query returns average growth by DayOfWeek by site.

Comment: Seems like you need to merge the second query with the first one and multiply Avg Growth values to Measure values. Also, noticed that all future Measure values are 0 in your sample data, 0 * average growth will be 0???

Comment: The future values are currently 0, but I would be estimating them by taking the corresponding last year value and multiplying it by the growth.
so 9/3/2019 estimated result, would be 9/4/2018's actual result * growth